# Error When Trying to Open a URL in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url

Environment: Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.0.3, Ubuntu

When I try to open a URL using:

```
open("http://www.cnn.com")
```

I get the following error:

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - http://www.cnn.com
    from (irb):9:in `initialize'
    from (irb):9:in `open'
    from (irb):9
```

(It's a difficult topic to search). This is happening in both irb and in my app. It used to work under Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.4 but it appears that something has changed.

Comment: Strange.. why not do this with .js?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I can reproduce the error if I try

```
open('http://www.google.com')
```

I'll get this error: `initialize': No such file or directory - http://www.google.com (Errno::ENOENT)

Instead, I required 'open-uri' in ruby 1.9.2 and it worked -

```
require 'open-uri'

url = URI.parse('http://www.google.com')
open(url) do |http|
  response = http.read
  puts "response: #{response.inspect}"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried something like this in Codecademy's exercise section.  Turns out that the request wanted a closing backslash.  Evidently `open('http://google.com/')` went through fine where `open('http://google.com')` did not.

Comment: Surprisingly, this actually solved the (404 not found) error I was receiving when trying to open an image url.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the error, in 1.8.7 I get a File object and in 1.9.2 I get a StringIO object. My guess is that some other code is overriding that functionality. Maybe you can try using the [Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/classes/Net/HTTP.html) object instead:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
Net::HTTP.get_print URI.parse('http://www.cnn.com')
```

or

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

url = URI.parse('http://www.cnn.com')
res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|
  http.get('/')
}
puts res.body
```